# How to remove tails from images when adding metadata with iptcinfo3 (python)?

Tags: python, iptcinfo

I'm working with from iptcinfo3, IPTCInfo. When I save metadata to the image, code below...

`info = IPTCInfo(image_file, force=True)`

adding metadata...

`...`

after that I save...
`info.save()`

and this is when new file is created that has ~. These files are not visible when I open folder, but if I go to terminal - and type `ls`, I can see these files, also these files are taking my space. I see this like this in my terminal;

```
image1.jpg
image1.jpg~
image2.jpg
image2.jpg~
image3.jpg
image3.jpg~
image4.jpg
image4.jpg~
image5.jpg
image5.jpg~
image6.jpg
image6.jpg~
```

How to delete files with ~, or change code that these are not created?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `overwrite` option in your `save` function.

```py
info.save(options='overwrite')
```

If you want to delete the files that end with `~`, run:

```bash
rm *~
```